# Using compass in WebStorm

Tags: compass-sass, css-sprites, webstorm

I've tried to add a 'compass' file watcher in WebStorm. Everything is going well but when I need to combine a large number of images into a single image sprite through WebStorm, the image output is corrupted. If I manually implement 'compass compile' in terminal then image output is fine.

So in summary,

Webstorm:

Sass compile = ok
Image auto spriting = fail

Is there anyway to fix this?

Update: screenshot of my setting

[image: screenshot of my setting]

Comment: please can you attach a screenshot of your file watcher? Or, even better, a sample project with all images you are trying to combine, so that we can see the error?

Comment: @lena screenshot attached, thanks lena

Comment: hmmm... what does your config.rb look like? Also, please can you attach your idea.log?

Comment: FYI: a post about using Compass with WebStorm - you might find it useful: http://caracaldigital.com/file-watcher-for-compass-in-phpstorm-webstorm/